# How should I use functions and / or combine some code here?

Tags: php, performance, function

I extended some tables with pagination and the possibility to sort columns. Everything is working fine so far, but I could use the very same code on up to 10 pages, so I thought about using functions, but I'm not sure if it's reasonable (performance etc.) to use a function for every part or if I should combine several things, so I need some advice..

Currently the code for one page looks like this (every number could be a function):

```
$limit = 30;
```

1.

```
$sql = 'SELECT
            COUNT(`news_id`)
        FROM
            `news`';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close()
```

2.

```
if ($count === 0)
{
    $max_pages = 1;
}
else
{
    $max_pages = (int)ceil($count/$limit);
}
```

3.

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $_GET['page'])
    && ($_GET['page'] > 1
    && $_GET['page'] <= $max_pages))
    {
        $current_page = (int)$_GET['page'];
        $offset = ($current_page - 1) * $limit;
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: http://' .SERVERNAME. '/admin/news/');
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $current_page = 1;
    $offset = 0;
}
```

4.

```
$valid_sort = array('id', 'date', 'title');

if (isset($_GET['sort']))
{
    if(in_array($_GET['sort'], $valid_sort))
    {
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: http://' .SERVERNAME. '/admin/news/');
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $sort = 'id';
}
```

5.

```
$valid_order = array('asc', 'desc');

if (isset($_GET['order']))
{
    if(in_array($_GET['order'], $valid_order))
    {
        $current_order = $_GET['order'];
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: http://' .SERVERNAME. '/admin/news/');
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $current_order = 'desc';
}
```

Since 4 and 5 are almost identical I could call the same function with different parameters here, but still I'm not sure if it really makes sense to call up to 5 functions..

Finally I need the following variables: `$limit, $count, $max_pages, $current_page, $offset, $sort, $current_order`

**EDIT** : Just to make it clear, the question is not how functions would work or if it's possible to use them here.. the question is, how complex should a function be relating to what I want to do with it? For example I could write one function with 120 lines and 8 parameters but I would only need to call 1 function / page... or I could keep it short and simple (1 function for 1 purpose / variable) but then I would need to call more functions / page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short. **Yes.**

It's fairly simple. If it's possible to put something in a function and make it re-usable, do so! It will organise your code and you can re-use it more easily. Otherwise you will have to rewrite your code afterwards to put it in a function anyway. So yes, do so and make it accessible for every single file if necessarily.

Also, if it's possible for you, try to start with functions to understand them completely, if you do, start with OOP! It will make your life so much easier. I hope this helps.

I am not going to rewrite your code, I think it's good practice for yourself if you do it on your own. If it's hard and you can't finish it yourself, feel free to ask on SO :)

- edit:
  About the performance you are talking about, don't worry. A function is maybe 0.00000000001 nanoseconds slower than copy pasting. But if you consider readability and programming into a count, use functions. If you don't care how your code looks like, and for a simple tweak you'd like to spend 5 days, don't use functions ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply! No need to rewrite my code, I can do that on my own :) using functions isn't completely new to me, but I'd rather need some advice if it makes sense to really use a function for every number (#2 does almost nothing so I'd guess calling a function here is overkill).. On the other hand I don't like to return an array and get the values using `list()`, since this could make a function getting big and too complex..

Comment: It's simple, if you are planning on re-using the pasted code, put it in a function so re-use is more easy. Try to build it as dynamic as possible, so you can change the whole thing by setting a few arguments in the function call.

Comment: I just edited my question to make it clear that I know how to re-use code using functions, but the question rather was, how complex it should be in that case :)

Comment: Hmm, in that case I would consider how you think the future will look like. Sometimes it's easier to just allow 1 argument as array, which can contain several parameters where you are going to loop through, that's 1 option. You can also allow 8 different args, but that means you will have to set everything but the ones you need to "null". So, consider the future: how do you think your application will look like in the future? How big will it grow? (which you can never actually predict, but should give you nice guidance when coding).

Comment: and that's exactly the point where I need some advice ;) my first "feeling" was to use 1 function for 1 purpose. That would provide maximum re-usability because I could use every function for itself (if I need to), while a more complex function is limited to what it was written for (unless I would use several if statements, but do I really want to call a 200 line function where 80% are unnecessary?)... but take a look at #2.. call a function for a single if..else statement? or call that function within another function?

Comment: What I should do in this case: if the functions of the 8 "parameters" as you might call them are completely different, make 8 stand-alone functions. If you need the functions where you can put an array in, because sometimes you have to run several at once, make a parenting function that calls the other individual functions. Maybe that's the way you are looking for? Gives you two ways of using the functions you need. I think that's usable? :)